# Docker Prometheus scrape API server on local host

Tags: localhost, prometheus

I have configured prometheus and alert manager to run in Docker desktop. Prometheus server is configured to scrape an API server (not dockerized) running onto the local host machine ( port:7080).

The communication between prometheus container and alert manager container is fine, but the rule I created to test if API server is up and running always sets an alert an then fires the alarm, even if the server is running. Everything is fine if i setup this environment in local host (no Docker).

I used the base image of the prometheus server which is download when the command is executed.

I tried many configuration for the targets parameter,

```
targets: ["localhost:7080"], 
targets: ["192.168.62.1:7080"], 
targets: ["localhost:7080"],
targets: ["host.docker.internal:7080"].
```

Here is my config - `Prometheus.yml`:

```
# my global config
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s # Set the scrape interval to every 15 seconds. Default is every 1 minute.
  evaluation_interval: 15s # Evaluate rules every 20 seconds. The default is every 1 minute.
  # scrape_timeout is set to the global default (10s).

# Alertmanager configuration
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
    - static_configs:
      - targets: ["172.17.0.3:9093"]
    
rule_files:
   - rules.yml
  

scrape_configs:
  
  - job_name: "Kernel"
    metrics_path: '/metrics'
    # metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
    # scheme defaults to 'http'.
    scheme: https
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["localhost:7080"]
```

rules.yml

```
groups:
- name: Kernel
  rules:
 
  - alert: Kernel Down Critical
    expr: up==0
    for: 30s
    labels:
      severity: critical
    annotations:
      summary: Kernel Down Critical
      description: Down fo more than 30s!!
      host: "{{ $labels.instance }}"
```

docekr command to create the container:

```
docker create --name Prometheus  --publish 9090:9090 --volume Prometheus-volume:/prometheus --volume C:\Users\t.domenici\Documents\prometheus-2.49.0-rc.0.windows-amd64/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml --volume C:\Users\t.domenici\Documents\prometheus-2.49.0-rc.0.windows-amd64/rules.yml:/etc/prometheus/rules.yml  prom/prometheus
```

Thanks

Comment: Attempts with ip and `host.docker.internal` [should work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/). What do you see on the targets page when one of them is configured?

Answer (score 0):

try adding the `--network host` to your docker run command and try to scrape and also share the error your recieve any from targets/service discovery page